# golf league scheduling

Tags: combinatorics

N golfers are to tee off in groups of 4 each week.  N is a multiple of 4 and all N golfers will play each week. The league organizer wants to go as many weeks as possible without any golfer playing in a foursome with another golfer with whom s/he has previously played.  Is there a formula that I can use to determine the number of weeks without playing with the same golfer?

Comment: Have you tried it for low values of N? That might lead you to your solution. It's the obvious beginning. N=4 obviously leads to one week. N=8 would still be one week, as would N=12 (only three groups, means at least two from the same group must go to the same group next week, having only 3 to choose from). So N=16 would seem to be the first time you get to two weeks.

Comment: I have tried for small numbers of N. For N = 16, the answer appears to be 5.   I have written this out.  I believe the answer of N=32 is still 5.  Does the number increase when N >64?  Beyond my specific problem, I am looking for a formula that works for any N and groupings of 2,3 etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is a special case of The Social Golfer Problem, for which no general solution is known. A [search on stack exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=social%20golfer%20problem) gives lots of information, plus there's a [demonstration on Wolfram Alpha](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/SocialGolferProblem/) that gives answers for up to 36 players.

There's also a famous related problem called Kirkman's Schoolgirl Problem (about fifteen girls walking in different triplets) which has lots of interesting posts on stack exchange, including a [generalization](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/397240/a-generalization-of-kirkmans-schoolgirl-problem).